# Using Hensel's lemma to solve congruence?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to use Hensel's lemma to solve the congruence

$$x^3 + x^2 - 5 \equiv 0 \pmod{7^3}$$

I begin by solving

$$x^3 + x^2 - 5 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$$

and observe that $x \equiv 2 \pmod{7}$ is the only solution. I then lift to a solution $\pmod{49}$, as follows:

$a_2 = a_1 - f(a_1)\overline{f'(a)} = 2 - f(2)\overline{f'(7)} = 2 - 7(\overline{161}) \equiv 2 - 7(\overline{0}) \pmod{49}$

However, obviously $\overline{0}$ doesn't exist, so $a_2$ is undefined... what did I do wrong?

Comment: In the end of the day, $\frac7{161}=\frac1{23}$, so try $2-1(\overline{23})$. The problem encountered here is taht $f$ and $f'$ are both multiples of $p=7$ here.

Comment: Sorry, why precisely am I allowed to do this?

Comment: In the original derivation of Hensel's lemma, we are looking for $a_2$ such that $(a_2-a_1)f'(a)\equiv -f(a_1)$. It is only in the case that $f'(a_1)$ is  invertible that we can transfer it to the other side immediately. In general, $f'(a)$ and $f(a)$ may have a power of $p$ in common that we may cancel away, i.e. $(a_2-a_1)f'(a_1) \equiv-f(a_1)\pmod {p^n}$ is the same as $(a_2-a_1)\frac{f'(a_1)}p \equiv-\frac{f(a_1)}p\pmod {p^{n-1}}$ if both $f'(a_1)$ and $f(a_1)$ are multiples of $p$. (So note that with the int from my fist comment you are back to $\pmod 7$ again instead of $\pmod{49}$)

Comment: Okay, hmmmm -- so $a_2 = 2 - 1(\overline{23}) = 2 - 1(\overline{2}) = 2 - 1(4) = 5 \pmod{7}?$ Do I need to compute two more lifts, one to $\mod{7^2}$ and one to $\pmod{7^3}$?

Answer (score 2):

With $\;f(x)=x^3+x^2-5\;$ (and everthing's done modulo $\;7^k\;$ in each stage)

**First lift** (modulo $\;7\;$ ):

$$f(2)=0\;,\;\;f'(2)=3\cdot2^2+2\cdot2=2\implies f'(2)^{-1}=4$$

$$t:=-\frac{f(2)}7f'(2)^{-1}=-\frac77\cdot4=-4=3$$

and then (passing now to $\;7^2\;$)

$$s:=2+3\cdot7=23\;\;\text{fulfilles}\;\;f(23)=0\pmod{7^2}$$

**Second lift** (modulo $\;49\;$):

$$f(23)=0\;,\;\;f'(23)=16\implies f'(23)^{-1}=-3=46$$

$$t:=-\frac{f(23)}{49}f'(23)^{-1}=-\frac{12691}{49}\cdot(-3)=777=91$$

and then (passing to $\;7^3\;$):

$$s:=23+91\cdot49=23\;\;\text{fulfills}\;\;f(23)=0\pmod{7^3}$$

(Yup, same $\;23\;$ in two modulos)